# What is 'click()' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with JavaScript in FireFox, and hit a problem that is illustrated in the following example:

```
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
function click()
{
    alert("click");
}

</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<input type="radio" onclick="click()">
</BODY>
```

When I click on the radio button, nothing happens, and no errors (in Firebug)

If I change the name of the function to do_click, and change the onclick, then I get the alert.

So question is: what is happening? click does not appear to be a reserved word, or an existing symbol

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Code within inline event handlers is scoped to the element, as if it was in a `with` block.

Therefore, within the `onclick` handler, the name `click` resolves to the element's `click` method.

This can be [demonstrated](http://jsbin.com/ugilu) by writing `alert(nodeName)` in the handler

Comment: Holy s*, I *never* knew this. Even behaves the same in IE. This seems so dangerous now....

Comment: There are so many properties hanging off of a DOM node. If a click handler was simply trying to set a global variable that happened to be named the same as one of the nodes properties (eg `innerHTML`), well.... *crap*.

Comment: Yet another reason to not put any real code in an inline handler.

Answer (score 10):

DOM elements have a native [click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) method.

The following will show that click is a native method:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="alert(click.toString())">
```

You can register your click function as the event handler as follows. Within the handler, `this` will refer to the HTML element.

```
<input type="radio" id="foo" >

function click()
{
    alert("click");
}
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = click;
```

There is an excellent series of articles about browser events at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the click() method in javascript simulates clicking the button. So this must be a sort of infinite loop...

Edited to add: Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752277(VS.85).aspx) for documentation of the click method

Answer (score 0):

'click' by itself is NOT a javascript [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words) outside the context of the inline event handler as Slaks answered.

That is to say the "click" method defined in the question is valid. Attaching the event handler 'externally' will work. E.g. using jQuery:

```
$('input').click(click);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think click() is a reserved procedure name, so you can't overwrite it. Explains why changing the name and nothing else gets it working.

Comment: "can't overwrite" is not correct. just that the target is different.