# JavaScript action inside HTML5 oninput attribute?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have been learning HTML5. One of the examples I have encountered uses an input element of type range and an output element (this example currently only works in Chrome, Safari and Opera).  The following form produces a slider with the result echoed to the output element.

```
<form>
   <p>
      <input type="range" id="slideValue" value="50" 
          oninput="slideCurrent.value = parseInt (slideValue.value);" />
      <output id="slideCurrent">50</output>
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

My question concerns the oninput attribute.  The oninput attribute contains JavaScript.  In pre-HTML5 JavaScript I commonly see JavaScript references to *this.value*.  However in the above HTML5 example the references to **slideCurrent** and **slideValue** work (apparently **without the need to use *getElementById***).  I believe this is a new way for JavaScript to behave.

Is this new JavaScript method of action documented somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2204568/34397

Comment: This could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: It is not new feature, just not very often used. See [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml)

Comment: I've found it used here http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_output.asp.  Maybe the use of this mechanism is being encouraged somewhere in relation to working with HTML5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code within inline event handlers is scoped to the element, as if it was in a `with` block.
Therefore, you can use properties of the element as global variables.

This is a little-known and [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2204538/34397#comment-2155504) feature, and is not new to HTML5.

Comment: I don't think that was the question

Comment: @Bergi: Apparently, it was.  However, upon re-reading the question, I believe you're right.

Comment: @Bergi, if I could have accepted your and SLaks answers I would have done.  Both increased my understanding of the situation.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's a method introduced by IE, that elements' names and ids are references in the global scope. Other browsers have copied it, but it's considered as bad use. Mozilla throws a warning:

> element referenced by ID/NAME in global scope. Use WC3 standard
>   document.getElementById() instead...

You can find lots of threads when googling for that. A good article can be found [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Mar/22/Internet-Explorer-Global-Variable-Blow-ups). In the event handler you can use `this`
as a reference to the element, but the output element should be acessed by standard dom methods.

EDIT: Oh shit, yes, its in the spec: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-window-nameditem. But with a big red alert:

> It is possible that this will change. Browser vendors are considering limiting this behaviour to quirks mode. [Read more...](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960)

See also Mozilla bugs [303420](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303420) and [602381](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602381)

Comment: Not correct, the problem is not globals, but accessing properties of the node from the inline handler as if they were globals, see Slaks explanation

Comment: @JuanMendes: So you say `slideCurrent` is a property of the range input?

Comment: I misread the question like Slaks did. What he says is true but doesn't apply in this example. Auto globals based on ids have been around for a while but like you said considered bad use. My bad....