# javascript, html5 forms . why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just beginning to learn javascript, so this is probably something very easy that I am overlooking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function calculatePayment()
    {
        //formula: M = P * ( J / (1 - (1 + J) ** -N))
        Monthlypayment.value=balance.value;

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="return false" name="MortgageCalculator" oninput="calculatePayment()">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Loan Basics</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="balance">Beggining Balance: </label><input type="number" name="balance" min="10000" max="5000000" step="10000" size="7" value="150000" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="rate">Interest Rate (%): </label><input type="number" name="rate" min="0" max="99" step=".25" size="4" value="4.5" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="term">Term (months): </lable><input type="number" name="term" min="6" max="360" step="1" size="3" value="360" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculatePayment()">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="calculations">
    <label for="MonthlyPayment">Monthly Payment: </label><output name="MonthlyPayment" for="balance rate term" form="MortgageCalculator" onforminput="Monthlypayment.value=balance.value"></output>
</div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

It seems to go to the function correctly, but I can't actually change the output to display anything.

Comment: You should start by : <script type="text/javascript">. Also consider running the script when the document is ready. If using jQuery just change $(function(){})

Comment: Are you sure `Monthlypayment` is not empty? Have you checked error console?

Comment: @Daniel I'm not using jQuery, should I be?

Comment: I believe that the `.value` of `input` fields in a form are as `strings`. You will have to use `parseInt()` to convert them to integers before performing calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to javascript I would like to suggest another method of performing calculations.

This method will be more readable and more flexible. As it stands, if there is a change to your formula you will have to change it in multiple locations.

I suggest creating `id`'s for each of your `input` fields.

In your javascript function I suggest creating variables with meaningful names. Finally you will need to use `parseInt()` as I believe that the `value` of `input` fields on a `form` are in `string` format.

**JS Fiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Y9L3/

**HTML:**

```
<label>Value 1</label>
<input type="number" id="value1"></input>

<label>Value 2</label>
<input type="number" id="value2"></input> <br>  

<button type="button" onclick="doMaths();">Calculate</button><br>

<label>Result</label>
<input type="number" id="result"></input>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function doMaths() {
var val1 = document.getElementById("value1");
var val2 = document.getElementById("value2");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

result.value = parseInt(val1.value) + parseInt(val2.value);
}
```

Comment: the calculations will be more complicated later, so I thought those names were good. I just started simple to see if it worked.. and it didn't.  But thank you for your help!

Comment: @the1gofer No worries, at the end of the day there are multiple ways to do what you want. With calculations I prefer something that's easy to read. Glad it was of use to you

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
Monthlypayment.value=balance.value;
```

with

```
document.MortgageCalculator.Monthlypayment.value=document.MortgageCalculator.balance.value;
```

reference: http://www.ryerson.ca/JavaScript/lectures/forms/textinput.html

It would also be good to read up on scope in javascript:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423447/2896173

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I added a couple edits.  Ahsan's answer is good.  But if you were wanting to do it from within the calculatePayment() function, you'll need to address the form elements by starting at the document object.

Comment: still doesn't seem to change anything ... see what I have here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/iajjf9qirieu11a/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can simply calculate in your form `oninput` as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" name="MortgageCalculator" oninput="MonthlyPayment.value = balance.value">
```

Remove the form tag from `Output` as it is already inside the `Form`:

```
<output name="MonthlyPayment" for="balance rate term">0</output>
```

You can also change your submit button as follows:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="MonthlyPayment.value = balance.value;">
```

Check the following reference for more details:

http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/

Comment: i simplified it in order to see if I could make it work before I started making real calculations.  So in the end I really do need a function to work .