# How to use image onclick event

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I 've got an image in my application. I try to change this image to another by onclick event, but I don't know why it doesn't work. 
Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div> 
  <img onclick="click()" src="http://chittagongit.com//images/smile-icon/smile-icon-6.jpg" id="smile">
</div>
<script>
  function click () {
    document.getElementByID("smile").src = "http://chittagongit.com//images/smile-icon/smile-icon-5.jpg"
  }
</script>
```

The same code at codepen:
https://codepen.io/szczypkamaciek/project/editor/DBrPbw

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: getElementById not getElementByID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check the console when things are working the way you expect. You misspelled "getElementByID" it should be "getElementById" (lower-case "d").

Also it's generally better practice to use addEventListener:

```
<script>
  var smile = document.getElementById("smile");
  smile.addEventListener('click', function () {
    smile.src = "http://chittagongit.com//images/smile-icon/smile-icon-5.jpg"
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake `document.getElementById` `Id` not with capital `ID`

```
function click() {
    document.getElementById("smile").src = "http://chittagongit.com//images/smile-icon/smile-icon-5.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this code:

1. Misspeled getElementById (insted of getElementByID)
2. Your code can't work in this form becuase you are using `click()` as your function name. Using `click` this way will fire click event, not your function - you can read more here: [click() in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204538/what-is-click-in-javascript)

Anyway in general it's better practise to use listeners instead of direct node declaration.